# Refactoring AngularJS Code - Extracting a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS app. The app is relying heavily on modules. I have a module that has a controller and a directive in it. The module looks like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp.component', [])
    .controller('ShellCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $gustoAreas) {
        $scope.myVariable = false;
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: function() {
                return '<div>Some HTML Goes Here</div>';
            },
            scope: true
        };
    })
;
```

I want to extract the function that holds the template so that I can just reference it by name. In other words, I want to do something like the following:

```
    .directive('myDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: generateTemplate(),
            scope: true
        };
    })
```

I'm a little green when it comes to JavaScript syntax. My question is, where do I define `generateTemplate` now? How do I call it? Do I need to use `generateTemplate()` or `generateTemplate` (with or without parenthesis)?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to define a value like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.component', [])
    .value('generateTemplate', '<div>Some HTML Goes Here</div>');
```

Or like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.component', [])
    .constant('generateTemplate', '<div>Some HTML Goes Here</div>');
```

And then just inject it into your directive or wherever else you will need it:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(generalTemplate){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: generalTemplate,
        scope: true
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extract your `generateTemplate` code to a service. Assuming that `generateTemplate()` returns a string containing the DOM, you must call it with parentheses.

You might be interested with the `templateUrl` option as well so instead of using a hardcoded `template`, you can use a separate HTML/template file to keep your code more modular.

Answer (score 0):

you can define generateTemplate in the global scope anywhere as 
    function generateTemplate() { ... }
before or after won't matter as it'll be compiled before.
you should not put parenthesis as it would trigger the function execution, while you simply need the function reference.

Comment: does generateTemplate returns a function or a string (as the function passed in parameter in your provided example)

In the first case (which is unlikely), you should use the parenthesis !